# Трансляция кода c Java 8 на Java 7

Tags: java, транслятор

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли проекты трансляторов кода (модуль из нескольких тысяч классов) с Java 8 в Java 7.
И насколько реально выполнить такую задачу?

Answer (score 3):

А гляньте проектик retrolambda - https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку @anber ! Действительно интересный проект. Но осталось пару вопросов. что означает "Does not backport Java 8 APIs" Это означает, что теми классами интерфейсами, коллекциями и тд. что появилось в JDK 1.8 пользоваться при разработке нельзя?
И если буду использовать, то бэкпорт будет не возможен?
Что означает "Also, backporting default methods won't work across module or dependency boundaries." Это означает, что если у меня программа разбита компоненты которые прелдставляют собой отдельные jar файлы, то после бэкпорта вызов дефолт метода из другого jar не будет работать?